# MS Access SQL code check

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working on some SQL code, but not proficient with MS Access so wanted to make sure it would behave like I think it should.

What I'm trying to do is get a count and the hour in military time for a set of records between june 1, 2015 to may 31, 2016.  I want to know how many records I have for each hour.  It doesn't matter what date the record took place on just the hour.

```
SELECT DatePart("h",[CentralTime]) AS Expr1, Count(DatePart("h",[CentralTime])) AS Expr2
FROM Master
WHERE (((Master.CentralTime) Between #6/1/2015# And #5/31/2016#))
GROUP BY DatePart("h",[CentralTime]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your query is fine and it will do what you want it to do.
I tend to prefer count('x'), and you can lose some of the parenthesis but your query will work as is.

Or use this:

```
SELECT DatePart("h",[CentralTime]) AS Expr1, Count('x') AS Expr2
FROM ShipandGetCalls_Master
WHERE ShipandGetCalls_Master.CentralTime Between #6/1/2015# And #5/31/2016#
GROUP BY DatePart("h",[CentralTime]);
```

And you may want to take a look at the filter about whether you want to include the data on 5/31/16.  You can change this field to a date/time to further specify exactly what you want to query to return.

Comment: Thank you for the response and advise.  By the filter do you mean like if I wanted only to 10 AM on 5/31/2016?